# Trouble with limit access to a Telegram Bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I am really new to python and I want my bot answers only limit users by their username.
I am trying to code this feature, but my bot send only one message "Not authorized".

What is wrong?

```
number_list.append(choice)
if update.effective_user.username not in  ["username"]:
    query.edit_message_text(text="Not authorized")
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use telebot api

```css
import telebot 

bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

username = ["USERNAME"]

@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def default_test(message):
    if message.from_user.username not in username:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Not authorized")
        
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Authorized")
        
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```